# Неправильные координаты и размер шрифта в Canvas drawText

Tags: java, android, canvas

Занимаюсь написанием корпоративной программы, одна из её функций, это наложении произвольного текста на новое фото. 
Для этого использую ImageView для отображения самого изображения и TextView для определение места нанесения текста, а также его размер, цвет и т.п.
Скриншот примера:
[image: неверное позиционирование текста]

Столкнулся с 2 проблемами:

1) Неправильно определяется позиция текста по оси Y. Побывал разными способами, остановился на такой функции (в x и y подаю координаты TextView, с помощью функции getX() и getY() соответственно):

```
private float[] getXY(ImageView iv, Bitmap bm, float x, float y){
        float projectedX = (float) ((double)x * ((double)bm.getWidth()/(double)iv.getWidth()));
        float projectedY = (float) ((double)y * ((double)bm.getHeight()/(double)iv.getHeight()));

        return new float[]{projectedX, projectedY};
    }
```

Пробовал через матрицу, результат ещё хуже. Может кто сталкивался? Как выровнять ось Y чтобы она соответствовала координатам.

2) Как видно на изображении, размер текста в TextView больше, нежели нарисованный с помощью Canvas, я понимаю что там играет роль разрешение самого изображения, но есть ли способ сохранить правильную пропорцию текста? Чтобы размер текста на пред просмотре соответствовал нарисованному размеру.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя зарубежные ресурсы - разобрался.
Смысл в том, что Canvas использует переданную позицию Y и пишет текст над ней. У любого TextView есть внутренние отступы, которые подымаю позицию ещё выше, хотя визуально - это не заметно. Т.е. чтобы получить хотя бы около приближенное расположение текста к нашему TexView нужно использовать вот такую функцию:

```
public float[] getPosition(ImageView imageView, TextView textView) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    imageView.getImageMatrix().invert(matrix);
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(textView.getText().toString(), 0, textView.getText().length(), bounds);
    float[] coord = {textView.getX(), textView.getY()+bounds.height()};
    matrix.mapPoints(coord);
    return coord;
}
```

Пока что, лучшего я не добился, но разница не критична, потому вполне подойдет для большинства случаев.

Чтобы нарисовать текст пропорциональный тому что мы видим в TextView, нужно умножить размер в пикселях на scalefactor, который равен - `(float)bitmap.getWidth() / (float) imageview.getWidth()`.

А для рисования текста использовать StaticLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что функции getX() и getY() возвращают позицию на экране! а это означает, что вы получаете позицию по Y с учетом тулбара и статус бара.
Из доки:

> It is possible to retrieve the location of a view by invoking the
>   methods getLeft() and getTop(). The former returns the left, or X,
>   coordinate of the rectangle representing the view. The latter returns
>   the top, or Y, coordinate of the rectangle representing the view.
>   These methods both return the location of the view relative to its
>   parent. For instance, when getLeft() returns 20, that means the view
>   is located 20 pixels to the right of the left edge of its direct
>   parent. In addition, several convenience methods are offered to avoid
>   unnecessary computations, namely getRight() and getBottom(). These
>   methods return the coordinates of the right and bottom edges of the
>   rectangle representing the view. For instance, calling getRight() is
>   similar to the following computation: getLeft() + getWidth()

перевод:

> Можно получить местоположение View путем вызова методов getLeft() и
>   getTop(). Первый возвращает левый край, или X, координата
>   прямоугольника, представляющего View. Последняя возвращает верхний
>   край, или Y, координаты прямоугольника, представляющего View. Эти
>   методы возвращают расположение View относительно его
>   View-предка(контейнера). Например, когда getLeft() возвращает 20, это
>   означает, что View находится на 20 пикселей правее от левого края
>   своего View-предка. Кроме того, несколько удобных методов
>   предлагается, чтобы избежать ненужных вычислений, а именно getRight()
>   и getBottom(). Эти методы возвращают координаты правого и нижнего
>   краев прямоугольника, представляющего View. Например, вызов getRight()
>   похожа на следующие выражение: getLeft() + GetWidth()

Вам лучше положить ImageView и TextView в один контейнер(например RelativeLayout) и используя эти методы получать координату на текущем изображении. Вам стоит учитывать scaleType, который вы указали для ImageView, т.к. это влияет наотображение исходного изображения и уже от этого отталкиваться в ваших вычислениях. Для отрисовки текста на изображении используются достаточно простые геометрические вычисления, которые нужно просто правильно организовать. А с размером текста вы правильно подметили, нужно учитывать разрешение изображения и текущий размер, а потом преобразовать размер текста по формуле (которую можно вывести, но этим надо заняться).

### P.S.

По оси X у вас небыло проблем потому, что у вас скорее всего вью прилягает к правому краю, вот поэтому getX() == getLeft().

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо за ответ. Все это находится в контейнере. Вот такая иерархия <LinearLayout><FrameLayout id=root><ImageView><TextView></FrameLayout></LinearLayout>. Т.е. все и так находится в контейнере

Comment: @evansir, ну вот, теперь используйте методы getLeft() (вместо getX()) и getTop() (вместо getY()). Потом, для позиционирования на канвасе изображения расчитайте realX = realWidth / currentWidth * getLeft() для realY аналогично, но с высотой, где realX - позиция по Х на реальном изображении, realWidth - реальная ширина изображения, currentWidth - текущая ширина изображения во View, getLeft() - позиция Х у TextView

Comment: Пожалуйста, обновите свой ответ с добавлением примера расчета координаты Y и размера текста.

Comment: getTop дает совсем не верный результат

Comment: @evansir, есть два варианта либо вы непонимаете как это работает и что возвращается, либо вы сделали ошибку в расчетах. Я надеюсь, что вы понимаете, что то, что вам возвращает getTop() это не позиция на канвасе для текста по Y, а только отступ в пикселях от верхнего края контейнера, а дальше вам надо самим расчитать позицию текста на канвасе по этим данным и взависимости от токого, какая там система координат.